# When to expect a `Cross-thread Exception`?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm having a hard time trying to understand what seems to be a random throwing of `cross-thread exceptions`.

**Examples**

When invoked in a different thread, why does this work:

```
Dim text As String = Me.Text
```

While this will throw an exception:

```
Me.Text = "str"
```

What makes it even stranger is that the following *do work*:

```
Dim text As String = Me.ctl.Margin.ToString() : Me.ctl.Margin = New Padding(1, 2, 3, 4)
Dim text As String = Me.ctl.MyProp : Me.MyProp = "str"
```

**Note**

Yes, I know that I could just invoke the property like this:

```
Me.Invoke(Sub() Me.Text = "str")
```

**Question**

So when can I expect a `cross-thread exception`?

**Code**

This is the code i used to test the `Me.Text` property:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Me.ctl = New Control()
        Me.ctl.Text = "test_control"
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.ctl)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TestGet(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf Me._Proc)
        t.Start(TESTTYPE.GET)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TestSet(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf Me._Proc)
        t.Start(TESTTYPE.SET)
    End Sub

    Private Sub _Proc(tt As TESTTYPE)
        Dim text As String = String.Empty
        Dim [error] As Exception = Nothing
        Try
            If (tt = TESTTYPE.GET) Then
                text = Me.ctl.Text
            ElseIf (tt = TESTTYPE.SET) Then
                Me.ctl.Text = "test"
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            [error] = ex
        End Try
        Me.Invoke(Sub() Me._Completed(tt, text, [error]))
    End Sub

    Private Sub _Completed(tt As TESTTYPE, text As String, ByVal [error] As Exception)
        If ([error] Is Nothing) Then
            If (tt = TESTTYPE.GET) Then
                MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("Success: '", text, "'"), tt.ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            ElseIf (tt = TESTTYPE.SET) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Success", tt.ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show([error].Message, tt.ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private ReadOnly ctl As Control

    Private Enum TESTTYPE
        [GET] = 0
        [SET] = 1
    End Enum

End Class
```

**Edit**

This will *not* throw an exception:

```
Public Event TestChanged As EventHandler

Public Property Test() As String
    Get
        Return Me.m_test
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        If (value <> Me.m_test) Then
            Me.m_test = value
            Me.Invalidate()
            RaiseEvent TestChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I did some research myself, and it turns out that the exception originates in the `.Handle` property of the `Control`.

```
<Browsable(False), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden), DispId(-515), SRDescription("ControlHandleDescr")> _
Public ReadOnly Property Handle As IntPtr
    Get
        If ((Control.checkForIllegalCrossThreadCalls AndAlso Not Control.inCrossThreadSafeCall) AndAlso Me.InvokeRequired) Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("IllegalCrossThreadCall", New Object() {Me.Name}))
        End If
        If Not Me.IsHandleCreated Then
            Me.CreateHandle()
        End If
        Return Me.HandleInternal
    End Get
End Property
```

*System.Windows.Forms.resources*:

> IllegalCrossThreadCall=Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '{0}' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

So I believe the answer would be something like this:

**`Whenever the handle of a control is invoked from a different thread.`**

(I'll give you all a vote up as all the answers are relevant towards cross-threading.)

The following code will throw an exception:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Test(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf Me._Proc)
        t.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub _Proc(id As Integer)
        Dim [error] As Exception = Nothing
        Try
            Dim p As IntPtr = Me.Handle
        Catch ex As Exception
            [error] = ex
        End Try
        Me.Invoke(Sub() Me._Completed([error]))
    End Sub

    Private Sub _Completed(ByVal [error] As Exception)
        If ([error] Is Nothing) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Success", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show([error].Message, Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Me.tbDescription.Text = [error].Message
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

the main time a cross-thread exception occurs when you do something that would cause an event to fire from the non-UI thread that affects the UI thread; So reading a property can be fine, but writing the property of a control would cause it to repaint (at the very least), hence the exception.

Of course, other vendors may have used the exception for other scenarios where it is not safe to access from a different thread

Comment: This may be true for some of the native properties/methods, but check my edit.

Comment: The cross thread exception comes along when the UI thread detects it - it may be the case that Invalidate does the Invoke for you; and your event doesn't touch the UI.

Comment: I know. This is dummy code not intended to be used. It's just for researching. I've posted an answer myself. If you have any thoughts whatsoever, please feel free to post a comment.

Answer (score 1):

> So when can I expect a cross-thread exception?

Really simple, when you access some `function` or `property` of a control, from a thread which do not have right to access it.

For example, in Window form application when you try to access the button placed on form from a non-ui thread, i.e. not the main thread, (and you have not set any flags manually to allow cross-thread operation)

**EDIT** As per comment, `how can I know I can/can not access a getter/ setter of a property. Where are the access rights defined?` you can always be on safe side by querying the control's `InvokeRequired` property in Windows

Comment: What do you mean by `rights to access`? As you can see in the example I _can_ access the `get_Text` method of the control, but the `set_Text` throws the exception.

Comment: `rights to access` means if I try to access the `function` or `property` for a control, from a `thread` which do not have right to invoke it.......

Comment: Do you mean [access levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx)? If yes, that is pretty obvious. If not, how can I know if I can/can not access a getter/ setter of a property. Where are the access rights defined?

Answer (score 1):

*So when can I expect a cross-thread exception?*

Well, GUI  in .Net  are created in  [STA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which means that only the thread that create the control can update it this has to do with Thread-safe concept. for this reasons when you start another thread and try to access the control  which is owned by the main thread you will  get an invalidOperationException

Comment: Then why can i call `Me.Invalidate()` from another thread than`Me` and still not get an exception?

Comment: Me refers  the curent instance like this in  c# is not another thread